# script to run 4 ping windows at 4 cornners of desktop Bath file

Tags: batch-file

How to run 4 ping windows at 4 cornners of desktop? Anyone help me?? Thanks!

[image: 4 ping commands on 4 cornners of desktop]

Comment: As your screenshot shows you already did it, so what do you want to know specifically? Please learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here!

Answer (score 1):

you can use nircmd which is freely downloadable [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to move the windows after creation

```
start "ping1" ping -t 127.0.0.1
start "ping2" ping -t 127.0.0.1
start "ping3" ping -t 127.0.0.1
start "ping4" ping -t 127.0.0.1

set SCREEN_WIDTH=1280
set SCREEN_HEIGHT=980
set /A WIDTH=%SCREEN_WIDTH%/2
set /A HEIGHT=%SCREEN_HEIGHT%/2

rem wait to be sure the windows are open
timeout /T 1
rem arguments syntax: x y width height
nircmdc win setsize title ping1  0 0 %WIDTH% %HEIGHT%
nircmdc win setsize title ping2  %WIDTH% 0 %WIDTH% %HEIGHT%
nircmdc win setsize title ping3  0 %HEIGHT% %WIDTH% %HEIGHT%
nircmdc win setsize title ping4  %WIDTH% %HEIGHT% %WIDTH% %HEIGHT%
```

It has to be configured for your display size, that's the main limitation.